# Upgrade from XP SP3 to Windows 8 doesn't work

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8

My OS is XP SP3.

The information I have followed says that I may be able to upgrade from XP3.

I have run the assistant

1. Run from the website.
2. Download and save, click on .exe.
3. Through "Run" in Start menu.

It doesn't work - I don't see any result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try running the EXE as an Administrator. To run a program as an Administrator in XP press SHIFT and hold, right-click the program icon, and then click Run as. Then log in with an Administrator account.

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version or the 64-bit one? You cannot upgrade to Windows 8 from a 64-bit XP SP3 as it is not a supported version.

Comment: @Rakib - Thanks. Will try. I am now at the point, following your direction where I have to set an administrator password. I'm not really adept so it takes me a little time. Plus 1 for the direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows XP to Windows 8 is a supported upgrade path, but, you would only keep your data - Installed applications/settings will be lost.

Please also make sure you use the same architecture upgrade (e.g. 64-bit and 32-bit installed versions need to be upgraded to the same).

Here is Microsoft's full upgrade path document from Technet - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx

[image]